# Как разобрать данные

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите пожалуйста. 
Имеется текстовый файл с такими данными

```
1533288817;34417469;03-08-2018;09:33:37;.press1;0.140544;
1533288818;34418471;03-08-2018;09:33:38;.press1;0.140544;
1533288819;34419468;03-08-2018;09:33:39;.press1;0.140544;
1533288820;34420472;03-08-2018;09:33:40;.press1;0.141258;
```

Как из него забрать значения 03-08-2018 09:33:37 0.140544 и т.д. и сохранить в файл press1

Comment: Использовать стандартный модуль [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться стандартным модулем csv.

Вот пример кода, который открывает Ваш файл, считывает из него нужные вам столбцы и записывает их в другой файл (т.к. Вы не указали, в каком формате нужно сохранять, то я привел пример записи в такой же csv файл):

```
import csv


def csv_reader(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')

        lst = []
        for row in reader:
            lst.append([row[2], row[3], row[5]])

        return lst

def csv_writer(rows, path):
    with open(path, "w", newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')

        for line in data:
            writer.writerow(line)

# Пример - открываем файл data.txt и записываем из него нужные стобцы в файл 
rows = csv_reader('data.txt')
csv_writer(rows, 'press1.txt')
```

Comment: Хороший у вас пример: содержит объяснение и код :)

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку

Answer (score 2):

"Наколеночный" вариант без модуля csv - просто разбить каждую строку методом `split()`:

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
    with open('out_file.txt', 'w') as out:
        for line in file:
            row = line.rstrip().split(';')
            print(row[2], row[3], row[5], file=out)
```

Плюсы такого метода: я редко пользуюсь модулем csv, поэтому чтобы им воспользоваться, мне нужно каждый раз смотреть примеры кода, а `split()` - всегда прямо здесь, на кончиках пальцев.

Когда удобнее использовать модуль csv - например, если в исходном файле есть строки с экранированием кавычек, точек с запятой и прочего. Тогда смотрим документацию, в `csv.reader()` выбираем диалект формата csv, разделитель, или все настраиваем под конкретный вариант csv, и работаем.